# Principle volume shader broken?

Tags: rendering, shaders, smoke-simulation, volumetrics

I have this large scene (20-30 meter domain) with smoke and fire. And wind. In object mode simulation looks fine, in render view with Principled volume shader it looks fine as well. But when i try to add emission strengh - all domain becomes completely white. Same happend with smaller domain in a fresh project. No idea where this issue might be coming from...

[image]

Comment: Solution in the Volume Info node. Flame output goes to Emission Strength and you can do bunch of stuff in between them with Color Ramps among others, including Attribute node. I found 'heat' attribute most useful for color of the smoke. I will continue gather information about this and will provide more profound answer later on

Answer (score 1):

The easy way to get flames is to use *temperature* attribute. Increase temperature to around 3500 (warm - yellowish color):

[image]

and add some *Blackbody Intensity*:

[image]

If you want, you can add some orange tint into it:

[image]